# ARIMA grid search for best $p$, $d$, $q$ orders based on BIC metric

Tags: arima, bic

i am new to R, and i was hoping to get some answers to some questions i have

1. is there a function to loop through a range of ARIMA model to get the best order/seasonal based on BIC/AIC ?
2. do i have always to difference the data if its not not stationary or there might be another reason to that and i dont have to take the differencing ?
3. i used Auto ARIMA to find the best ARIMA model based on its BIC, and i specifically specified BIC perimeter in the Auto ARIMA function but when i tried to use some candidate ARIMA order i was able to get a lower BIC than what the Auto ARIMA got, how is that possible ?
4. what could be a better practice, to use the differencing time series data in the arima function , or to use the original one and specify that there is an order of d there?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Use `forecast::auto.arima(data, ic="bic")`
2. No. `auto.arima()` will determine the number of differences needed for you.
3. `auto.arima()` will avoid models which could be numerically unstable. For example, the fitted model could have near unit-roots.
4. Over-riding the automatic selected order of differencing is sometimes useful. But make sure you are aware of the consequences. See https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html#understanding-constants-in-r

Comment: thank you Dr.Rob , but i might not have made it clear, but in my first questions i was asking about a function that can use a range of orders like the one in JMP. As you look at the ACF, PACF and and what could be the suggested candidate orders and then use a range of them to have JMP loop through that range and spit out the one with the minimum BIC/AIC according to your choice

Comment: auto.arima allows you some control over what models are included in the search. See the help file. The ARIMA function from the fable package provides even more control.